# How to synchronize multiple canvases when panning on the base canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, canvas

I have two canvases:

The first one serves as the base canvas, visible to the user on the screen, where panning and mouse events are handled.
The second one is a hidden background canvas where the user actually draws, and its content is exported to the first canvas.
Everything works as expected until I pan the base canvas (or scale it, but both have the same issue since the transforms of the two canvases do not match).

After panning the base canvas, I believe the mask canvas must also be panned to synchronize. However, the same code that I use to pan the base canvas does not work for the mask canvas. I have researched other panning methods, but I don't think I fully understand how the synchronization between the two canvases should be achieved.

You can find a live demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-typescript-starter-z6xncr?file=src%2FApp.vue.

I'll share the code where I update the base canvas's transform since analyzing the entire code is resource-intensive.

**Template**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="tool-section">
      <button @click="tool = 'free-pan'">Free Pan</button>
      <button @click="tool = 'draw-mask'">Brush</button>
      <button @click="tool = 'eraser'">Eraser</button>
    </div>
    <canvas
      @mousedown="baseCanvasMouseDown"
      @mouseup="baseCanvasMouseUp"
      @mousemove="baseCanvasMouseMove"
      @mousewheel="baseCanvasTouchStart"
      ref="baseCanvas"
    ></canvas>
    <canvas style="display: none" ref="maskCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>
```

Watcher for **currentOffset** (The variable that holds the current offset of the canvas, also obtainable by using canvas.getTransform()):

```
currentOffset: {
  handler(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (this.baseContext && this.maskContext) {
      const offsetDiff = this.scalePoint(this.diffPoints(newValue, oldValue), 1)
      this.baseContext.translate(offsetDiff.x, offsetDiff.y)
      // this.maskContext.translate(offsetDiff.x, offsetDiff.y)

      this.viewportTopLeft = this.diffPoints(this.viewportTopLeft, offsetDiff)
      this.updateCanvas()
    }
  },
  deep: true,
}
```

**Methods**

```
updateCanvas() {
  this.updateTransform()
  this.drawBaseImage()
  this.maskContextToBaseContext(0, 0)
}

updateTransform() {
  if (this.baseContext) {
    const storedTransform = this.baseContext.getTransform()
    this.baseContext.canvas.width = this.baseContext.canvas.width
    this.baseContext.setTransform(storedTransform)
  }

  // if (this.maskContext) {
  //   const storedTransform = this.maskContext.getTransform()
  //   this.maskContext.canvas.width = this.maskContext.canvas.width
  //   this.maskContext.setTransform(storedTransform)
  // }
}

drawBaseImage() {
  if (this.baseContext) {
    this.baseContext.drawImage(
      this.baseImage,
      (window.innerWidth - this.baseImage.width) / 2,
      (window.innerHeight - this.baseImage.height) / 2
    )
  }
}

maskContextToBaseContext(x: number, y: number) {
  if (this.baseContext && this.maskCanvas) {
    this.baseContext.globalAlpha = this.globalAlphaValue
    this.baseContext.drawImage(this.maskCanvas, x, y)
  }
}
```

When I uncomment the code where I translate the mask canvas, it does not draw at all.

You can better understand the issue by checking other mouse events in the demo link.

Comment: You can (and likely should) use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to demonstrate the issue here on Stack Overflow.